# How do I clip voltage between ±0.5 for ADC input?

Tags: diodes, protection, surge-protection, schottky

I have an ADC which accepts 0.5 to -0.5 V for input. How do I clamp the voltage at the input of the ADC to assure protection and maintain voltages between 0.5 to -0.5? Any Suggestion?

Comment: What ADC takes that small of a range?  Is it really half a volt?

Comment: If you want someone to offer a good solution, you need to provide more information. What ADC are you using? What configuration, if applicable? What will it be reading the value from? What current will that be able to source? Dmitry's answer is good. But depending on your requirements and that of the ADC, it might not be what you want. You need to give more information.

Comment: @Jodes: Yes, you are correct, I should have included the ADC information. I was given this constraint by my professor so, I took that as a constraints and was trying to work through.

Comment: This is really an inadequate specification for a sensible design. You need to have a difference between operating voltage limits and clamp voltage limits, and an idea of how much inaccuracy can be introduced as well as a bunch of other things. Dmitry's solution (while it might be a practical one, given a sensible spec), for example, will have a very large error at +/-0.5V in and high Ta, and will not clamp the voltage to 0.5V in general (for example, +/-2V in and -40°C Ta, it will have about +/-0.65V out).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `diodes` in your tags I believe you already know the solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMxdIJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Different diodes have different voltage drop values, usually within 0,2-0,7V. You'll have to find diodes which don't exceed 0,5V. Also you don't provide any information regarding typical frequency of your circuit. Again, look up typical diode capacity `C` in the datasheet and make sure `R1*C`'s cutoff frequency is above your frequency range.

Comment: Yes, I kind of knew the solution but wasn't 100% sure of clipping the ±0.5 Voltage (really small).